# jQuery isNumeric issue

Tags: jquery, isnumeric

Trying to run the following jQuery script and although the passed value is certainly an integer it silently fails (no debug errors) at isNumeric. No alerts after this either (but the first one does confirm the passed value is an integer)

It's probably something very simple, but I have stared at it and changed it for so long the code fever is approaching :-)

Any hints would be appreciated

```
function loadFromManager(HOAID) {
        alert('function - ' + HOAID);
        if ($.isNumeric(HOAID)) {
            alert('IsNumeric = true');
            if (HOAID > 0) {
                alert('HOAID > 0 = true');
                window.name = HOAID;
                window.location.href = '/HOA5/secure/landing/';
            }
            else {
                alert('HOAID > 0 = false');
                window.location.href = '/HOA5/secure/redirect/';
            }
        }
        else {
            alert('IsNumeric = false');
            window.location.href = '/HOA5/secure/redirect/';
        }
        alert('End of function');
    };
```

Comment: I just found something out - debugging with Edge does nothing!!! I changed the default browser in VS to IE and found the error straight away. The page didn't load _Layout so jQuery wasn't even added!! Sigh.

Comment: Some debuggers have certain filters, like showing when something fails to load. Have you checked those in Edge?

Comment: Hi Xufox - it looks like there is an ongoing issue with Edge (maybe that is why they are throwing up their hands and going to move onto the Chromium engine.) I also have noticed that once the browser is closed VS still stays open in debug mode, another complaint. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/9115072-support-javascript-debugging-for-microsoft-edge